# Toggle through tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I currently have a jQuery which displays 4 tables simultaneously, how could I get it to display 1 table at a time with a toggle though button?

i have displayed part of my code below. Any help would be great thanks.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function call_everybody(){                                 
        display_cyclist_results_table();
        display_cyclist2_results_table();
        display_cyclist3_results_table();
        display_cyclist4_results_table();
        cyclist_heading();
    }
 </script>

    <table class="resultsTable" align="center"> 
            <tr><td class="tdCells"><div id="cyclist_table"></div></td>
                <td class="tdCells"><div id="cyclist2_table"></div></td>
                <td class="tdCells"><div id="cyclist3_table"></div></td>
                <td class="tdCells"><div id="cyclist4_table"></div></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they all have the same class, something like this should work

```
var $tables = $('.resultsTable');//cache table elements to avoid repeated dom searches
$tables.not(':first').hide();

$('#someButton').click(function(){
    var $currTable = $tables.filter(':visible').hide(),
        nextIndex = $tables.index($currTable) +1;           
    if(nextIndex === $tables.length){
         nextIndex = 0;
    } 
    $tables.eq(nextIndex).show();   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Set your tables' display to none. Assume all tables have class `my_table` Add a class ( e.g. `show` ) to the one which is supposed to show, and then use jQuery to remove the class from the current and add it to the next table.

**CSS:**

```
.my_table {
    display: none;
}
.my_table.show {
    display: table;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var tblNum = 0;
var tblTotal = $('#table_container .my_table').length;
$("#toggle_table").on('click', function() {
    $('#table_container .my_table').removeClass('show');
    tblNum++;
    if(tblNum >= tblTotal)
        tblNum = 0;
    $('#table_container .my_table').eq(tblNum).addClass('show');
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/vc27cfqy/4/)